# How to extract individual points for a detected rectangle in OpenCV C++?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I'm trying to access individual points from conPoly[i]. It is a <vector<vector>. The thing is I can't select the individual points to save them in another indivual variables.

I want to extract the points from the detected rectangle to make a warpPerspective. How can I do that so I can extract this points?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int edge_max=206,edge_min=54;
int trackbar_edge_max_value = 500;
int half = 2;
Mat imgWarped;

void getContours(Mat imgCanny, Mat img)
{   
    
    vector<vector<Point>> contours;
    vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
    string objectType;
    findContours(imgCanny, contours, hierarchy, RETR_EXTERNAL, CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

    for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
    {
        int area = contourArea(contours[i]);
        //cout << area << endl;

        vector<vector<Point>> conPoly(contours.size());
        vector<Rect> boundRect(contours.size());

        if (area > 60000)
        {
            float peri = arcLength(contours[i],true);
            approxPolyDP(contours[i], conPoly[i], 0.02 * peri, true);
            //boundRect[i] = boundingRect(conPoly[i]);
            cout << boundRect[i] << endl;
            int objCor = (int)conPoly[i].size();
            if (objCor == 4)
            {
                objectType = "Dreptunghi";
                //rectangle(img, boundRect[i].tl(),boundRect[i].br(), Scalar(0,255,0),5);
                cout <<conPoly[i]<<endl;
            }

            
            
        }
    }
}

void main()
{   
    string path = "Lumina_Slaba/6.jpeg";
    Mat img = imread(path);
    //VideoCapture video("http://192.168.1.8:8080/videofeed");
    Mat imgBlur, imgGray, imgCanny,imgWarped;

    

    //Creare trackbar pentru reducerea numarului de linii din poza
    namedWindow("Eliminare detalii", (100,640));
    createTrackbar("Valoare Maxima","Eliminare detalii", &edge_max, trackbar_edge_max_value);
    createTrackbar("Valoare Minima", "Eliminare detalii", &edge_min,trackbar_edge_max_value);

    //Procesare imagine
    resize(img, img, Size(), 0.5, 0.5);
        while (true)
        {
            //video.read(img);
            GaussianBlur(img, imgBlur, Size(5, 5), 5, 0);
            cvtColor(imgBlur, imgGray, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
            Canny(imgGray, imgCanny, edge_min, edge_max,3,true);
            getContours(imgCanny,img);
            imshow("Detectare Cota Tehnologica 1", imgCanny);
            imshow("Detectare Cota Tehnologica", img);
            waitKey(1);
        }
}
```